# leave the house or leave home?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Which one is natural when you refer to the place where you live, not just a constructed dwelling ?

> A: Hey honey, I will give you a call when I leave the house.
>
> B: Hey honey, I will give you a call when I leave home.

Somehow, "the house" sounds more natural to my ears in this case but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: In my opinion, both are perfectly fine and widely used.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "the place where you live, not just a constructed dwelling."  The place where people live is a constructed dwelling (unless they live in the street).  Do you mean the constructed dwelling in which the speaker lives as opposed to some other constructed dwelling?

Comment: Note that _leave home_ can also mean _leave one's parents to go and live on one's own_, a meaning I wouln't read in _leave the house_ (cf. The Beatles, _She's leaving home_)

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, but the context here prevents that interpretation.

Comment: There's an emotional connotation to the word 'home', implying that your home is where you live and "feel at home".  Despite the best efforts of real estate salespeople, not every house is a home, nor is every home a house.  Though there's a good bit of overlap n everyday speech, I would say "leave home" when I leave my house, but "leave the house" when I'm leaving some other house that I'm just staying at temporarily.

Comment: @oerkelens I was also going to use that song as an example, but the OP hasn't clarified what he/she means yet.

Comment: @pazzo - The way I read it, the O.P. already knows that "house" can refer to anyone's house. So, if I'm at Ben's house, I would say, "I'll call you when I leave the house." The O.P. is asking which is more appropriate when you leave your own house (home).

Comment: I am not sure of that @J.R. or I would have written an answer more than 24 hours ago. ;)

Comment: @pazzo - I'll admit I'm speculating some, but I think there's some evidence that I'm on the right track, based on the comment by the O.P. under user3169's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or the other might be more common for people living in houses in certain areas, but I've heard both and both sound completely fine to me.

I would be less likely to say 'house' if my home was not actually a house. I currently live in a split-level townhouse, and sometimes refer it to as "my house" and sometimes as "my home". When I live in an apartment, I use "my apartment" or sometimes "my home". So, I would say "my home" is more common simply because 'home' includes more types of dwellings than 'house'.

If 'honey' is aware that I'm at home, I would probably just say "when I leave" without specifying what type of residence I'm leaving.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use both, but in this scenario I would go with:

> A: Hey honey, I will give you a call when I leave **the house**.

As a physical action this is fine.

But while a *house* is a *home*, *home* also refers to the more emotional perception of where you live, including family relationships and such.

Comment: I think that interpretation on the end is a stretch.

Comment: Considering **context** there would be no interpretation that she was moving out... also, I don't know why the gender of the person matters at all.

Comment: Actually, this is why I feel reluctant to use "leave home". I am not a native English speaker so I don't feel that I can argue. However, I have a feeling that "leave home" does not necessarily have to mean "terminate a relationship". I can only guess though.

Comment: @PerfectGundam A college student, for example, may say "I'll give you a call when I leave home" implying they're on the way to the airport from their parents' house... but there's still **context** that distinguishes what is meant. The college student might be less likely to refer to their dorm as "home" but as long as you're an adult and you're talking about the place you live and consider your "home", you can use this version of the phrase.

Comment: @Catija I agree the use of "honey" in the example negates my interpretation. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Luckily, it could be differentiated by using a dictionary.

Definition of house by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/house):

> a building in which people live; residence for human beings.

Definition of home by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/home):

> a house, apartment, or other shelter that is the usual residence of a person, family, or household.

---

> A: Hey honey, I will give you a call when I leave the house.

It could be anyone house, or technically a building (perhaps in the case when I'm homeless).

> B: Hey honey, I will give you a call when I leave home.

This is confirmed, it's **home**, it is my usual shelter.

---

Short answer to your question: Both

Comment: Dictionaries are not reliable sources of information about this kind of thing. The phrase "leave home" suggests moving out of your parent's house or going on a long journey. So, people tend to favor "leave the house" for what the OP is asking about. Also, the wording of your answer is condescending. Please write respectfully; everyone here is doing their best to learn, and reference materials are often confusing or misleading.

Comment: _"Also, the wording of your answer is condescending."_ I'm also learning, and I don't think one's reply should be regarded as *condescending* just by the fact that he has mislead someone unintentionally.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is condescending because it's mistaken, but because of "Answer to your opinion-based question" and the suggestion that the OP should simply have looked the words up in a dictionary. Perhaps I misunderstood, though. "Opinion-based" is a common reason to say that a question is not appropriate for StackExchange because it doesn't have a factual answer (in which case you should vote to close it or suggest improvements rather than post an answer, as explained [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/936/6700)).

Comment: It can indeed be difficult to tell, when learning a new language, what sounds condescending and what doesn't!

Comment: -1 Your interpretation is incorrect. This is not how native speakers always use these words.

Comment: The dictionary is of little help here. The O.P.'s question correctly implies that either could be used, but is looking for guidance from native speakers.  Moreover, your assertion that "It could be anyone [sic] house" is irrelevant; the question asks about leaving **the place where you live**. And there's no need to label this an "opinion-based question" in your answer; I will edit that out.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that it meant _to leave the house **e.g.** to the shopping centre fetch you back._ I didn't know OP was referring to run away from home. The sentence is quite common in my region, Singapore. As for the *opinion-based*, it's really *opinion-based* that's why as a different person from far region misunderstood. Anyway, please completely delete this answer from public view. Thanks!

Comment: @XPMai I'm fine with this answer as it is. If you want it deleted, you can delete it yourself with the delete link right under the text.