# Do "periodically leave the house" and "periodically go out of the house" mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning

[A post says](https://www.cnet.com/health/16-coronavirus-tips-how-to-help-keep-yourself-healthy-when-going-out-in-public/)

> As coronavirus lockdown restrictions ease and cities reopen around the world, the way you'll go to restaurants, malls and hair salons will change, so it's a good idea to think about how you'll keep yourself and your loved ones healthy during a prolonged period.
>
> If you're not part of a vulnerable group, becoming a hermit isn't necessarily the solution, either. It's beneficial to **periodically leave the house** to maintain your health and sanity and run critical errands, but there are measures you can take when coming within spitting distance of people outside the household.

Does the following mean the same thing?

> ... "**periodically go out of the house**" ...

Do both of them mean "going out in public for a few hours"?

Is it grammatically correct and natural?

---

[leave the house or leave home?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58399/115654) is related to this topic, though no one there talks about whether it sounds natural.

Comment: _Leave the house_ is a verb phrase (on its own, it could be finite or inifinitive, but in context, it is infinitive. _Going out of the house_ is a gerund or participial clause, and is not grammatically the same. _Go out of the house_ would have the same grammar. _Go out_ and _leave_ don't have precisely the same meaning, but they're pretty close.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you. I should have said "go out of the house".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Leave the house" is how you would describe departing to go somewhere else, such as going to work, for example:

> I leave the house at 8am every morning to reach work by 8:30am.

"Go out of the house" could mean just to step outside of it - for example, into the garden, for example:

> If you go out of the house you'll see the damage to the door.

There is an idiomatic use of "get out" which is often used to mean leaving the house to go elsewhere, for example:

> It's nice to get out of the house for a while and go for a walk.

Comment: Thank you. So, "periodically go out of the house" is better to convey the idea that the original post is trying to suggest, right?

Comment: @PutBere I would just say "go out", rather than "go out of the house".