# go to work at a specific time

Tags: meaning

This one comes from [Do "periodically leave the house" and "periodically go out of the house" mean the same thing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/248626/115654)

> I leave the house at 8 am every morning to reach work by 8:30 am.

with that schedule, should I say

> I go to work at 8 am every morning

or

> I go to work at 8:30 am every morning

Comment: Both are potentially ambiguous, though if the subject of the conversation is 'leaving the house' this may not be a problem. If you want to make it absolutely clear, you need to say _I leave for work at 8.00. I start work at 8.30_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is further context, "go to work at 8" would normally mean the time when you leave home.

If this is critical, then "leave for work", "get to work" and "start work" can be used.

> I go to work at 7am.
>
> I leave for work at 7am and get there at 8.  I usually have a cup of coffee while the computer boots up, then start at 8:15.