# meaning of "leave home" in different areas

Tags: meaning

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave)

> If you **leave home**, you stop living in your parents’ home.

[leave the house or leave home?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58399/115654) verifies this usage.

whereas, [go to work at a specific time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/248633/115654) uses "leave home" this way

> Unless there is further context, "go to work at 8" would normally mean the time when you **leave home**.

I understand the meanings of all the sentences above clearly, I would just like to know if the usage of "leave home" varies in different areas. For example, in some area, "leave home" only means "stop living in parents’ home" while in some other area "leave home" could also mean "go out of house for something".

Is my understanding right? If yes, what are those areas?

Comment: It varies in different _contexts_, not different areas. When talking about your daily routine, _leave home_ would be understood to mean _set out for the day_. When talking about where a young person lives, it means _move out of your childhood home_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. For instance, "*I will give you a call when I leave home*" from that link, doesn't give a clear context. So, the meaning of "leave home" is ambiguous there. Is my understanding right?

Comment: I don't consider it to be really ambiguous, because _giving someone a call_ is normally part of everyday happenings rather than something as momentous as moving house. Someone who is moving out of their parents' home might say 'I'll get in touch when I'm settled in my new flat," but not 'when I leave home'.